# What does this vertical bar in an equation mean?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, optics

I'd like to know what the vertical line followed by an E represents in this image. I would Google it, but I don't know what to type in to Google.[image]

Comment: I would say "value of Fy in point  E, times small change in y". But it should be explained in the source paper.

Comment: Math Overlow would have been a better home for this question.

Answer (score 3):

A vertical line, with a subscript usually means
"evaluate the expression before it at the value of S, where S is the subscript.

However, in the absence of context, it may possibly mean something else.

Comment: That *something else* can often also just be a restriction to a domain.